# Div Items Move Up on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four `<div>`. One of them is not displayed using `display:none` and is only displayed once you click an icon. When the item is clicked jQuery toggle function is called. One `<div>` is set to `display:none` and the one which was previously hidden is displayed. This is working perfectly but for some odd reason the page content moves 10 pixels or so up on toggle. I don't know what's causing it as all the `<div>` have same css and classes. Here is the css:

```
element.style {
margin-right: 5px;
margin-left: 10px;
left: 0px;
display: block;
}

#contactus {
background-color: #DDD;
position: relative;
position: relative;
left: 0;

}
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.span4 {
margin-left: 5px;
width: 320px;
}
```

span4 is the class for the toggled divs. Element styling is also the same. Can any one give me a hint what is causing this behavior. Here is the url:
http://contestlancer.com/davidicus/
You can see it the problem if you click on message icon besides the logo heading.

Ahmar.

Comment: your use of bootstrap grid system has some problems

Comment: You need to have 12 columns in a row but you have 16 also the `h2` element should be outside the row element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a height to your logo header eg

```
height: 90px;
```

Comment: Thanks Liam I thought margin-bottom will keep it in its place. My bad